# How to use crypto.subtle.wrapKey to wrap an RSA-PSS private key using AES-KW?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptography, aes, webcrypto-api

I'm getting the following error when trying to wrap an RSA-PSS key using AES-KW:

```
The AES-KW input data length is invalid: not a multiple of 8 bytes
```

It works sometimes though, but only when the length of the output of the key in 'pkcs8' format is divisible by 8. That is perhaps also stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey.

My question then is: Is it not possible to wrap an RSA-PSS key using AES-KW? I can't find any padding option. If not, is my best option to go the IV route?

See below code:

```
export async function wrapKeyAsync(key: CryptoKey, password: string) {

    let keyMaterial = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        new TextEncoder().encode(password),
        { name: "PBKDF2" },
        false,
        ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"]
    );

    let salt = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));

    let wrappingKey = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {
            "name": "PBKDF2",
            salt: salt,
            "iterations": 100_000,
            "hash": "SHA-256"
        },
        keyMaterial,
        { "name": "AES-KW", "length": 256 },
        true,
        ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]
    );

    console.log((await crypto.subtle.exportKey("pkcs8", key)).byteLength / 8); // Only works when input is divisible by 8

    return {
        wrappedKey: new Uint8Array(await crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
            "pkcs8",
            key,
            wrappingKey,
            "AES-KW"
        )),
        salt
    };
}
```

Comment: *Is it not possible to wrap an RSA-PSS key using AES-KW?* Not without padding, since the 8 bytes constraint exists for AES-KW and RSA keys generally do not fulfill this. *I can't find any padding option.* You can theoretically apply e.g. PKCS#7 padding (and de-padding) for an 8 bytes blocksize. *If not, is my best option to go the IV route?* To me, AES-GCM seems more appropriate in this case (although I can't give a compelling knockout criterion for AES-KW).

Comment: @Topaco thanks! I'll go the GCM IV route then :) couldn't find the PKCS#7 padding option in the web crypto api.

Comment: OK, although the [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) should not be the main reason, since this can be implemented with little effort.

Comment: @Topaco you sure? although the specification seems effortless; modifying the behaviour of the web crypto api's wrapKey() seems not to be possible. although I might be mistaken.

Comment: No, meanwhile I don't think AES-KW is reliably usable for RSA. I thought you could wrap the RSA key as a raw (PKCS#7 padded) key. But WebCrypto doesn't allow that, because a CryptoKey must be associated with a valid algorithm.